# add phtml file in every cms page

Tags: magento2, xml

I just started working on magento 2 and i want to call a phtml file for every cms page.
I have created a theme and under Magento_Cms i have copied cms_page_view.xml from vendor and placed it in there.Now i added below code there.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>


    <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
        <body>
            <referenceContainer name="content">
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Page" name="cms_page"/>
            </referenceContainer>
            <referenceContainer name="maincontent">
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Page" name="custom.page.title" before="-" template="Magento_Cms::page/title.phtml"/>
            </referenceContainer>
        </body>
    </page>
```

page/title.phtml placed inside Magento_Cms/templates/page/title.phtml and i used die there.. and after flushing cache my phtml is not getting call. I am not able to see die effect on page. Please suggest me how can i render custom phtml file for all cms pages using xml

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create custom module and copy core cms_page_view.xml in your module's view/layout/ folder

use this code in cms_page_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
              <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="test" template="Aman_Custom::test.phtml"></block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

I have tried with custom module its working fine.